# Optimizing some pandas melt + groupby + pivot logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization

I am trying to optimize as much as possible some code which includes these pandas lines:

```py
df = df.groupby(by=['cat1','cat2'], sort=False).cumcount() + 1
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['cat1','cat2','cat3'], value_vars=['feat1','feat2'], var_name='feature')
df['index'] = 'aa'
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index='index', columns=['cat1,'feature','cat2','cat3'], dropna=True)
```

It's doing a transformation taking a dataframe looking like:

```
|    | cat1   | cat2   |   feat1 |   feat2 |
|---:|:-------|:-------|--------:|--------:|
|  0 | c1v1   | c2v1   |     123 |     nan |
|  1 | c1v1   | c2v1   |      26 |     392 |
|  2 | c1v1   | c2v1   |     131 |     271 |
|  3 | c1v1   | c2v1   |     122 |     177 |
|  4 | c1v1   | c2v1   |     164 |     251 |
|  5 | c1v2   | c2v1   |     130 |     290 |
|  6 | c1v2   | c2v2   |     121 |     464 |
|  7 | c1v2   | c2v2   |      81 |     238 |
|  8 | c1v2   | c2v2   |      55 |     381 |
```

to a single line multi index column looking like

```
| index   |   ('c1v1', 'feat1', 'c2v1', 1) |   ('c1v1', 'feat1', 'c2v1', 2) |   ('c1v1', 'feat1', 'c2v1', 3) |   ('c1v1', 'feat1', 'c2v1', 4) |   ('c1v1', 'feat1', 'c2v1', 5) |   ('c1v1', 'feat2', 'c2v1', 2) |   ('c1v1', 'feat2', 'c2v1', 3) |   ('c1v1', 'feat2', 'c2v1', 4) |   ('c1v1', 'feat2', 'c2v1', 5) |   ('c1v2', 'feat1', 'c2v1', 1) |   ('c1v2', 'feat1', 'c2v2', 1) |   ('c1v2', 'feat1', 'c2v2', 2) |   ('c1v2', 'feat1', 'c2v2', 3) |   ('c1v2', 'feat2', 'c2v1', 1) |   ('c1v2', 'feat2', 'c2v2', 1) |   ('c1v2', 'feat2', 'c2v2', 2) |   ('c1v2', 'feat2', 'c2v2', 3) |
|:--------|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|-------------------------------:|
| aa      |                            123 |                             26 |                            131 |                            122 |                            164 |                            392 |                            271 |                            177 |                            251 |                            130 |                            121 |                             81 |                             55 |                            290 |                            464 |                            238 |                            381 |
```

Or in pretty form:

[image: before] to

[image: after]

I see that I am doing a melt and a pivot, and since they are close to be inverse one of each other there may be a easy speedup. The total time on my machine is 30ms ish, which I want to bring down to a half. I am not willing to give up on using pandas here, yet.

**UPDATE**

@dankal444 suggested doing the pivot and melt by a manual for-loop and storing results in a dict before casting it into a dictionary. I tried and noticed a speed-up. Here is the code:

```py
df['typing_index'] = df.groupby(by=['cat1', 'cat2'], sort=False).cumcount() + 1

pivoted_table_entries = {}
for row in events.values:
    if not np.isnan(row[-3]):
        pivoted_table_entries[(row[0], 'feat1', row[1], row[-1])] = [row[-3]]
    if not np.isnan(row[-2]):
        pivoted_table_entries[(row[0], 'feat2', row[1], row[-1])] = [row[-2]]

pivoted_table = pd.DataFrame(pivoted_table_entries,
                                     index=['aa'])
pivoted_table.columns = pivoted_table.columns.set_names(['cat1', 'feature', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
```

If I profile this code I see that most of the CPU time (~90% of it) goes into creating the DataFrame. Is there a way to speed this up by transforming the data beforehand or else?

Comment: Example data would help

Comment: @U12-Forward Have added a more detailed - and hopefully helpful - example.

Comment: @Learningisamess in this example df is missing. When you say you are "not willing to give up on using pandas here" do you mean you want result to be pandas df or whole code to use only pandas operation (without using to dicts/numpy)?

Comment: @dankal444 I mean I want the input and output to be dataframes

Comment: @Learningisamess then consider iterating over df.values, creating temporary dict, save there what you want and then creating result_df out of this dict. If you provide full example, with input df, I could show you exactly what I mean.

Comment: @dankal444 thanks for the suggestion, I have tried your technique and I can see a significant speedup. Let me update the question.

Comment: @Learningisamess ok, now what may be faster (my guess) is extract keys and values from the dict, (optionally make numpy arrays out of them) and put this into df creation: `pd.DataFrame(data=dict_values, index=dict_keys)`

Comment: @dankal444 great tip, extracting they keys and values (and taking a transpose of the dataframe) gives a -60% speed up on that line of code!

Comment: I have tried the manual numpy casting, but it seems to bring no speed up.